# Удаление записи в таблице MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь удалить запись в таблице, но не получается.
Этот участок кода работает исправно:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO players ".
        "(Name,Age,Club) ".
        "VALUES ('$name',$age,'Snakes') "; 
        echo "inserted";
    }

    else
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE players ". 
        "SET Age = $age ". 
        "WHERE Name = '$name'" ;
        echo "updated";
    }
```

Вот так пытаюсь удалить:

```
$sql = "DELETE players ". "WHERE Name = '$name'" ;
```

На что получаю данную ошибку:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Name = 'Cat'' at line 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `players` WHERE `Name` = '$name'" ;
```

Comment: В PHP переменная в кавычках распознаётся, как переменная, а не строка?

Comment: В двойных - да. Хотя профессионалы все же рекомендуют использовать одинарные кавычки и конкатенацию. Такой код всегда будет работать быстрее и читаться лучше.